# How to retrieve firebase list on ionic 3 that would be update when there is change?

Tags: javascript, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have a list of items, I want the list to be updated when I added new item and also when I update existing item.

By using 'child_added' to retrieve the list, the new item will be added to the list immediately after I add new item, but when I modified existing item, the change on the item is not reflected on the list.

When I use 'child_changed', it will not show the list at all as it seems that the list was not retrieve using 'child_changed'.

Please advise the proper way of retrieve a firebase list on ionic 3 that would be update when there is change detected.

Below is my script;

```
  getItems(category: string){
    let items: Item [] = [];
    var itemRef = firebase.database().ref('items/'+category);

    itemRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
      items.push({
        item_id: data.key,
        name: data.val().name,
        color: data.val().color,
        description: data.val().description
      });
    });

    itemRef.on('child_changed', function(data){
      //not sure what to do here
    });

    return items;
  }
```

Comment: child_added events iterate over the list initially and then any time a new child is added that child is presented to your app in a snapshot. child_changed only presents the child that was changed. Generally using a combination of the two (or three with child_removed) is best practice. Have you tried that?

Comment: I'm not really sure on how to combine both child_added and child_changed. I provide my code on the main question above.

Answer (score 2):

The `child_changed` event fires when a node has changed. At that point you will need to find the old data in your array and replace it with the new data:

```
let items: Item [] = [];
var itemRef = firebase.database().ref('items/'+category);

itemRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
  items.push({
    item_id: data.key,
    name: data.val().name,
    color: data.val().color,
    description: data.val().description
  });
  // TODO: add the item to the UI
});

itemRef.on('child_changed', function(data){
  items.forEach(function(item, i) {
    if (item.item_id === data.key) {
      items[i] = {
        item_id: data.key,
        name: data.val().name,
        color: data.val().color,
        description: data.val().description
      };
    }
  })
  // TODO: update the item in the UI
});
```

Note that I removed the `getItems()` function around this code. You cannot **get** items from Firebase and return them from a function. Instead you should think of the problem as "Start loading items from Firebase. Whenever a new item is added, add it to the UI. Whenever an item is updated, update it in the UI." This way of thinking is known as reactive programming, and is the key to building apps on many modern web technologies.

Comment: thanks for your guidance, it works. Just a small typo, on if query you type, it should be `if (items[i].item_id`

Comment: Thanks for catching that! It was actually meant to be `item`. Fixed it now. :-)